# How to arrange the chip in second row when the first row is filled in linear layout horizontal?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am facing the problem in arranging the text view, i am dynamically creating the chips in a linear layout horizontal view, when i created the multiple chips only few chips are viewing the remaining are hidden,how to arrange the chips in second row when the first row is filled.Please help me how to solve this.

The below code is for dynamically creating the chips in linear layout

```
LinearLayout    linearChip  = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_chip);
   Chip chip = new Chip(this);
   chip.setChipText(tag);
   chip.setClosable(true);
   chip.setPadding(10,0,0,0);
   chip.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
   chip.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
   chip.setCloseColor(Color.BLACK);
   chip.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   chip.setOnCloseClickListener(new OnCloseClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCloseClick(View v) {
               linearChip.removeView((View) v.getParent());
       }
   });

   linearChip.addView(chip);
```

}